# Given a DCEL, how do I find the closest pair of sites?

Tags: algorithm, voronoi

Given a DCEL, how do I find the closest pair of sites?

Say the given DCEL is for a Voronoi diagram, how do I find the closest pair of sites? And what is the time complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to iterate over all edges, find their adjoining faces, compute the distance between the Voronoi centers, and return the smallest pair.  If your DCEL implementation is such that you cannot iterate directly over edges, you can use any graph-traversal algorithm (depth-first, breadth-first, etc.) to do the iteration.

In any case, the time complexity is proportional to the size of your input datastructure.

Comment: But how do i get the sites in the Voronoi diagram? The voronoi diagram contains only the esges and the vertices of the VD>

Comment: If the DCEL is for a Voronoi diagram (as in your question), then the site information should be attached to the faces.  If you don't have the site information any more, you have problems -- are you asking how to reconstruct the original sites from the Voronoi vertices?

Comment: Another way to put it:  each half-edge in a DCEL typically has both a `face` pointer to its face, and an `origin` pointer to its vertex (as well as `next` and `twin` pointers to edges).  If you have control over your DCEL structure and it doesn't have a `face` pointer, then add one.  But if the Voronoi diagram you get from some library doesn't have any face data, one could be forgiven for asking "why not?"